# Android studio 3.0 rendering "Exception raised during rendering" and "onMeasure error"

Tags: java, android

I got some rendering problem after I updated my Android studio to version 3.0.

I've tried to change the SDK version like this but still didn't work.

[Picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzgvU.png)

My JDK version is 1.8 and here is some of my gradle information.

```
compileSdkVersion 26

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.wheathermaster"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

I also tried "Clean project" and "Invalidate Cache/ Restart", but none of them works.

And here are my error messages:

Exception raised during rendering

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.graphics.BidiRenderer.getScriptFont(BidiRenderer.java:290)
at android.graphics.BidiRenderer.getScriptRuns(BidiRenderer.java:280)
at android.graphics.BidiRenderer.renderText(BidiRenderer.java:133)
at android.graphics.BidiRenderer.renderText(BidiRenderer.java:108)
at android.graphics.Paint_Delegate.measureText(Paint_Delegate.java:1318)
at android.graphics.Paint_Delegate.nGetTextAdvances(Paint_Delegate.java:975)
at android.graphics.Paint_Delegate.nGetRunAdvance(Paint_Delegate.java:1154)
at android.graphics.Paint.nGetRunAdvance(Paint.java)
at android.graphics.Paint.getRunAdvance(Paint.java:2734)
at android.graphics.Paint.getRunAdvance(Paint.java:2766)
at android.text.TextLine.getRunAdvance(TextLine.java:732)
at android.text.TextLine.handleText(TextLine.java:778)
at android.text.TextLine.handleRun(TextLine.java:1018)
at android.text.TextLine.measureRun(TextLine.java:417)
at android.text.TextLine.measure(TextLine.java:307)
at android.text.TextLine.metrics(TextLine.java:281)
at android.text.BoringLayout.isBoring(BoringLayout.java:294)
at android.widget.TextView.makeSingleLayout(TextView.java:7960)
at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout(TextView.java:7853)
at android.widget.TextView.assumeLayout(TextView.java:7754)
at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:6807)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19192)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19062)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:4236)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:63)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19060)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:4236)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:63)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19195)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19062)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:4236)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:63)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19060)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:4236)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:63)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19060)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:4236)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:63)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19060)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:4236)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:63)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19195)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.renderAndBuildResult(RenderSessionImpl.java:403)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.renderAndBuildResult(RenderSessionImpl.java:541)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:424)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.BridgeRenderSession.render(BridgeRenderSession.java:108)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.RenderSession.render(RenderSession.java:154)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.RenderSession.render(RenderSession.java:136)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$renderInner$5(RenderTask.java:757)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

onMeasure :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.graphics.BidiRenderer.getScriptFont(BidiRenderer.java:290)
at android.graphics.BidiRenderer.getScriptRuns(BidiRenderer.java:280)
at android.graphics.BidiRenderer.renderText(BidiRenderer.java:133)
at android.graphics.BidiRenderer.renderText(BidiRenderer.java:108)
at android.graphics.Paint_Delegate.measureText(Paint_Delegate.java:1318)
at android.graphics.Paint_Delegate.nGetTextAdvances(Paint_Delegate.java:975)
at android.graphics.Paint_Delegate.nGetRunAdvance(Paint_Delegate.java:1154)
at android.graphics.Paint.nGetRunAdvance(Paint.java)
at android.graphics.Paint.getRunAdvance(Paint.java:2734)
at android.graphics.Paint.getRunAdvance(Paint.java:2766)
at android.text.TextLine.getRunAdvance(TextLine.java:732)
at android.text.TextLine.handleText(TextLine.java:778)
at android.text.TextLine.handleRun(TextLine.java:1018)
at android.text.TextLine.measureRun(TextLine.java:417)
at android.text.TextLine.measure(TextLine.java:307)
at android.text.TextLine.metrics(TextLine.java:281)
at android.text.BoringLayout.isBoring(BoringLayout.java:294)
at android.widget.TextView.onMeasure(TextView.java:8125)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1148)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:687)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:958)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure_Original(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure_Original(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:400)
at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.measureView(RenderSessionImpl.java:590)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:343)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:384)
at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:193)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:544)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$3(RenderTask.java:678)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes android studio unable to preview layout so  **Change your android version** **on your designer preview into your current version** depend on your Manifest. rendering problem caused your designer preview used higher API level than your current android API level.

Happy coding!!

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I changed **font.xml** to old one and it solved.
I don't know what font causing this error but this worked for me.

Comment: I finally  solved it by updating my Android studio to 3.2. I'll try to change font.xml after my current works done.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer but updating your IDE AndroidS to 3.2 shoud solve your probleme. Cheers ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just close the Android Studio, delete the `.android` and `.gradle` files and then open the android studio again. The problem should resolve.